# 'reactions.resolve' returning undefined after the timer is finished | Discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have it set so once 12 hours is over It would collect reactions from the sent message and so on. This never caused an issue with me whilst I was hosting it from my PC. But when moved to an online host it would give me this error and shut down the bot once 12 hours is over:

Console output:

```
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] reactionMessage.reactions.resolve('������').users.fetch().then(userList => {
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] ^
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] at /commands/suggestion.js:72:51
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
21.10 14:58:00 [Bot] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Code:

```
        sEmbed.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 15, time: 43200000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            let cacheChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID); 
            if(cacheChannel){
                cacheChannel.messages.fetch(db.get(`${suggestionID}.MessageID`)).then(reactionMessage => {
                    reactionMessage.reactions.resolve('⬆️').users.fetch().then(userList => {
                        db.set(`${suggestionID}.Upvoted_Users`, ((userList.map((user) => user.id).length) - 1));
                        db.set(`${suggestionID}.Total_Users`, 15);
                        db.set(`${suggestionID}.Downvoted_Users`, db.get(`${suggestionID}.Total_Users`) - db.get(`${suggestionID}.Upvoted_Users`));
                        GV.checkValues(db, suggestionID, sEmbed, message, icon, discord);
                    });
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            change = true;
            GV.lessVotes(change, suggestionID, sEmbed, db, message, icon, discord);
        });
```

Just as a note, it did cause some slight issues moving the bot online where it told me sql_lite3 was compiled in VER 73 and needs VER 92 when I already have VER 92 of Node.js installed. So to run the bot I use `npx node index.js` instead of just `node index.js` I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue or not.

EDIT: I've changed `npx node index.js` to `node index.js` don't know if that'll fix the error or not but just wanted to throw that out there.

Also, Now the bot gave another error in 12 hours (before the change):

```
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, 
request);
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] ^
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at RequestHandler.execute (/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at async RequestHandler.push (/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at async MessageManager.react (/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:193:5)
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at async Message.react (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:690:5)
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at async /commands/suggestion.js:57:13
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] at async Object.run (/commands/suggestion.js:56:27) {
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] method: 'put',
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] code: 10008,
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] httpStatus: 404,
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
22.10 10:08:03 [Bot] }
```

It says the error is at line `27` in the `suggestions.js` file, Although that's just a simple send command to the channel that has no issues at all as well. I'm starting to think this was because of `npx` and now that it's gone I'm gonna have to wait another 12 hours to confirm

Comment: Is this in a command handler?

Comment: Yes, but it works normally in a command handler with no issues.